# Is there an algorithm that can compute finite presentations for finitely presentable subgroups in a FP group with solvable word problem?

Tags: group-theory, recursive-algorithms, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, decision-problems

Given a group and its finite presentation $G=\langle A\mid R\rangle$, I want the following algorithm:

Input: a finite set $W$ of words in $A\cup A^{-1}$ that generates a finitely presentable subgroup in $G$,

Output: a finite presentation of the subgroup generated by $W$.

I observed that the existence of such an algorithm solves the word problem in $G$, since one can input $W=\{w\}$, and by checking if the output is trivial or isomorphic to a non-trivial cyclic group, they know whether $w$ represents the identity element in $G$.

So if $G$ has solvable word problem, does such an algorithm exists? Specifically I'm working on $G$ being a Right-Angled Artin Group or a Mapping Class Group, so an answer for any of these two classes of groups will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It is very unlikely that such an algorithm exists in general. It is a strange question, because you are assuming that you somehow know that the given subgroup is finitely presentable. How would you know that? Deciding that is known to be unsolvable even for subgroups of hyperbolic groups.

Comment: I am not aware of many algorithms of any kind for computing presentations of subgroups of finitely presented groups. One such algorithm that I know about applies to subgroups that are coset automatic, one example of which is quasiconvex subgroups of hyperbolic groups. Unfortunately, although RAAGs are automatic, their finitely generated subgroups are not well behaved in general, even for direct products of free groups. Do you have any explicit examples that you would like to calculate?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your help! Actually I'm working on the "finitely presented subgroup isomorphism problem" of RAAGs and mapping class groups. [https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5416](Martin) showd that it is unsolvable for some RAAG and thus for all big mapping class groups. I want to show that this problem is recursively enumerable (i.e. there exists an algorithm that enumerates all isomorphic pairs of fp subgroups). This is done immediately if one can find the above algorithm. On the other hand I somewhat believe that if the problem is indeed r.e. then such algorithm exists.

Comment: @DerekHolt I just checked again about Martin's statement, I think there the "finitely presented subgroup isomorphism problem" is taking a pair of "finite presentation of subgroups" as input, not only a pair of "generating set of finitely presentable subgroups". If that is indeed the case, such an algorithm is not required to show that the problem is r.e.. But thanks anyway for your help! I've also found [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117) might be useful.